# want to assign roles specific to email address with regex or any other solution for it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, regex, email, logic

```
r.d.fred-2021@hull.ac.uk (for student)
r.d.fred@hull.ac.uk      (for teacher)
```

I want to assign roles as a student if it includes year otherwise teacher during user registration.

what would be the regex expression for this or any other optimal solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following regex

```js
const str1 = "r.d.fred-2021@hull.ac.uk";
const str2 = "r.d.fred@hull.ac.uk";

const regex = /[0-9]{4}/;

console.log('str1 has year -- ', regex.test(str1));
console.log('str2 has year -- ', regex.test(str2));
```